# How to deal with padding in convert?

Tags: imagemagick

I am using convert from PDF to PNG.

```
$ convert -density 203.294113 -resize 6000x3300\> src.pdf[0] dst.png
```

But when the image is created, it has a white margin added around the origin pdf page and I don't know how to eliminate it (it doesn't matter whether "density" and "resize" are used). Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: How about using -extent?

Comment: "-extent" does not work very well, still has white margin. I suspect the problem appears at lower level, maybe ghostscript? When it prints the PDF into image, a white surrounding margin is automatically added...

Answer (score 2):

you can use `-shave` to remove border with specific size or `-trim` to auto-trim image

Comment: "-shave" needs to have specific size, which is not easy to get (or please tell me how to get the dimension of PDF, I am not familiar with that). "-trim" will cut out the original margin of the PDF, which is not desirable? Any better idea?